# How to get value from react-select in a functional component React

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am making use of react-select for the first time in a form. I am having issues getting the value from the select input and send it via Axios to backend.

```
const options=[
  { value: 'Telecomms', label: 'Telecomms' },
  { value: 'Construction', label: 'Construction' },
  { value: 'Manufacturing', label: 'Manufacturing' },
]
function Register(props) {
  
  const [newUser,getUser]=useState({
      name: "",
      businessSector:"",
     
  })

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

// onChange handler
  const changeHandle=e=>{
  
    getUser({
      ...newUser,
      [e.target.name]:e.target.value

    })
  }

  const SubmitHandle=e=>{

    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(newUser)
   
    if (newUser) {
        dispatch(registerUser(newUser))
       
    }
  
  }


 return (
    <FormDialog
      loading={isLoading}
      onClose={onClose}
      open
      headline="Registration"
      onFormSubmit={SubmitHandle }
      hideBackdrop
      hasCloseIcon
      content={
        <Fragment>
          <Grid Container spacing={20}>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            name="name"
            value={newUser.name}
            onChange={changeHandle}
            required
            fullWidth
           
            label="Full name"
            autoFocus
            autoComplete="off"
            type="text"
            InputProps={{
              className: classes.input
            }}
            FormHelperTextProps={{ error: true }}
          />
          
           <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Business Sector</InputLabel>
         <Select
         value={newUser.businessSector} 
         onInputChange={changeHandle}
          options={options}
          name="businessSector"
          />
```

Any time i try to select an option is gives the following error

```
Type error: cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I am wondering where am actually getting it wrong. If I try to check the state from the dev tools, its not registering on state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Type error: cannot read property 'name' of undefined` comes from the use of `[e.target.name]` in your `changeHandler`. You're using the wrong prop/callback for this; instead of `onInputChange` use `onChange`:

```js
  const onChangeHandler = (change) => {
    getUser({
      ...newUser,
      businessSector: change
    });
  };

 return (
      <Select
        value={newUser.businessSector}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        options={options}
      />
 );
```

`onInputChange` is for when the input changes so if you were using the `isSearchable` prop you'd be able to type inside of the Select input and that would send the event `e` you're expecting to get, but because its just a select it returns an empty string instead.

Comment: Thanks, its solved! ."change" is an object and so, i got the "sector label" by doing {change.label}